# Is there a sequence where the average of the squares is proportional to the square of the average?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Usually in math, the order of operations matters when you do anything more complicated than addition or multiplication. If you have a list of numbers, whether you apply the average or the squaring first gives different results. But can you build a sequence where the order doesn't matter? Let's say there's a sequence of numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and $a_k=f(k)\ne constant$. What functions $f(x)$ could you choose so that $$\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2=c \cdot\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2$$
where $c$ is a constant that is independent of $n$?

Edit: I believe that if $a_1\ne0$ or $a_2\ne0$, then $c\le1.5$

Since $c$ is independent of $n$, I can plug in $n=2$ into the equation.
$$\left(\frac12\sum_{k=1}^2a_k\right)^2=c \cdot\frac12\sum_{k=1}^2a_k^2$$

$$\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2=c \cdot\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{(a_1+a_2)^2}{4}=c \cdot\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2}{2}$$

$$(a_1+a_2)^2=2c(a_1^2+a_2^2)$$

$$a_1^2+2a_1a_2+a_2^2=2c(a_1^2+a_2^2)$$

$$2a_1a_2=2c(a_1^2+a_2^2) - (a_1^2+a_2^2)$$

$$2a_1a_2=(2c-1)(a_1^2+a_2^2)$$

$$a_1a_2=(c-1/2)(a_1^2+a_2^2)$$

Now let's assume that $c\gt1.5$ so that $c-1/2\gt1$. There are two possibilities: $a_1^2+a_2^2$ is positive or $a_1^2+a_2^2$ is zero. For the first case we multiply both sides of the inequality $c-1/2\gt1$ by the positive number $a_1^2+a_2^2$ to get

$$(c-1/2)(a_1^2+a_2^2)\gt a_1^2+a_2^2$$

If $a_1^2+a_2^2$ is zero then

$$(c-1/2)(a_1^2+a_2^2)= a_1^2+a_2^2$$

so $(c-1/2)(a_1^2+a_2^2)\ge a_1^2+a_2^2$ in general. Now we know that

$$a_1a_2=(c-1/2)(a_1^2+a_2^2)\ge a_1^2+a_2^2$$

$$a_1a_2\ge a_1^2+a_2^2$$

$$a_1a_2-2a_1a_2\ge a_1^2 -2a_1a_2+a_2^2$$

$$-a_1a_2\ge (a_1-a_2)^2$$

$$-a_1a_2\ge (a_1-a_2)^2\ge0$$

$$-a_1a_2\ge0$$

$$a_1a_2\le0$$

combine this with $a_1^2+a_2^2\le a_1a_2$ to get

$$a_1^2+a_2^2\le a_1a_2\le0$$

$$a_1^2+a_2^2\le0$$

A sum of squares can't be negative so $a_1^2+a_2^2=0$ which means that $a_1=a_2=0$. We started with the assumption that $c\gt1.5$ so

$$c>1.5 \implies a_1=0 \;\text{and}\; a_2=0$$

$$a_1\ne0 \;\text{or}\; a_2\ne0 \implies c\le1.5$$

Let me know if something's wrong with this argument; if it's correct, can it be used to find $f(x)$ or prove it doesn't exist?

Comment: Could you try recursively building this sequence i.e. start with $a_1$, then build $a_2$ so that the equation is satisfied, then find $a_3$ so that the sequence is satisfied, etc.? At each stage I believe it comes down to the existence of real solutions of some quadratic equation. It may also happen that the equation has no real solution, in which case you can conclude that no such sequence exists.

Comment: I admire your work, it's correct. However, it turns out you can do better at the very start. Indeed, $$\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2 \leq \left(\frac{|a_1|+|a_2|}{2}\right)^2 \leq \frac{a_1^2 +a_2^2}{2}$$ by the AM-RMS inequality. Therefore, unless $a_1=a_2=0$, it must in fact hold that $c \leq 1$.

Comment: After plugging in some values, I think the rule is that if $m$ is the minimum $k$ such that $a_k=0$ then c = $\frac1m$

Comment: I think you're right, but what if no $a_k = 0$? Then see what happens?

Comment: In my last comment, I meant to say $m$ is the minimum $k$ such that $a_k\ne0$. If $m$ doesn't exist, then the entire sequence is just repeated zeroes. But that would go against the condition that $a_k=f(k)\ne constant$

Comment: Ah ok, I see. If that logic is extrapolated by letting $m$ go to infinity, then it seems that no non-constant sequence $a_k$ can exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the first $n$ such that $a_n\ne 0$. Then $\left(\frac 1N a_N\right)^2=c\cdot\frac 1N\cdot a_N^2$, so $c=\frac 1N$.

For each natural $n\ge N$ put $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$ and $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n^2$.
Then $\frac 1{n^2}S_n^2 =\frac cn T_n=\frac 1{nN} T_n$, that is $S_n^2=\frac nN T_n$. But $S_{n+1}=S_n+a_{n+1}$,
$T_{n+1}=T_n+a_{n+1}^2$, so $$(S_n+a_{n+1})^2=\frac{n+1}N(T_n+a_{n+1}^2)=$$ $$\frac{n+1}N(S_n^2\frac{N}n+a_{n+1}^2)=\frac {n+1}n S_n^2+\frac {n+1}N a_{n+1}^2.$$

It follows
$$n(n-N+1)a_{n+1}^2-2nNS_n a_{n+1}+NS_n^2=0,$$

so $$a_{n+1}=\frac{2nNS_n\pm\sqrt{4n^2N^2S_n^2-4n(n-N+1)NS_n^2}}{2n(n-N+1)}=$$
$$S_n\cdot \frac{nN\pm\sqrt{n(n+1)N(N-1)}}{n(n-N+1)},$$
and both sign choices are possible.

Moreover, we have $N>1$. Indeed, otherwise $N=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{S_n}n$. Therefore
$$a_{n+2}=\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}+S_n}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}+na_{n+1}}{n+1}=a_{n+1},$$
so the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is constant, a contradiction.

Comment: A possible slight simplification : $n^2N^2-n^2N+nN^2-nN=nN(n+1)(N-1)$

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $(S_n+a_{n})^2=\frac{n+1}N(T_n+a_{n}^2)$ ?

Comment: @MumboJumbo No. I fixed this issue. Sorry for the misprints and thanks for your attention.